# how to use expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp inside test method

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I would like to use assert exception type and message in testng @test , where my requirement is to pass the expected message from outside data source which looks not easy to passing as parameter with @test

Tried this testng solution

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = StatusRuntimeException.class , expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp ="ExceptionMsg")
```

want to achieve something like the given Junit example

```
  @Test
public void testMethod(){

valiadteException();      

}
public void valiadteException(){      
 exception.expect(StatusRuntimeException.class);
        exception.expectMessage("ExceptionMsg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a regular expression that does not match the output message.

If you are expecting a part of the full message, try using:

```java
@Test(expectedExceptions=StatusRuntimeException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp =".*ExceptionMsg.*")
```

This will check that the message contains `ExceptionMsg` somewhere in the message.

However, if `ExceptionMsg` is the full message you expect, you must escape the regular expression special characters for it to work.

Special characters like `.` must be escaped by adding the escape character `\` in front of the special character like so: `\.`

I cant give more info without a more concrete message. If you add the message you are expecting, I can give its escaped version in my answer.

**EDIT:**

If you want something like the second one, I dont know if it exists in testng, however you could accomplish it like this:

```java
@Test
public void testMethod(){
    // test code
    try {
        // call function/method that throws the StatusRuntimeException
    } catch (StatusRuntimeException ex) {
        // validate the exception
        Assert.assertTrue(ex.getMessage().contains("ExceptionMsg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Trey , This solve half of my problem however would it possible to add expectmsg parametert inside method instead of parameter .

Comment: instead of using this  ```@Test(expectedExceptions=StatusRuntimeException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp =".*ExceptionMsg.*" ```  I want to write in this way  ```@Test Public void testMathod(){expectedExceptions=StatusRuntimeException.class;expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp =".*ExceptionMsg.*"}```

Comment: I've added to the answer. Let me know if that works for your case.